# Book recommendation request: A good C++ based software development book for a computational mathematician

Tags: c++, software

I'm hoping that this type of question is on-topic, and I have put in a little hunting to make sure it isn't a flat out repeat. If it is either of the above, I apologize in advance.

I'm an early career computational mathematician who is at least minimally capable with C++, and pretty proficient with something like MATLAB, so the act of writing code itself is not generally a major issue for me. I most often use libraries developed by others, but even when coding doesn't hold me back I'm constantly finding myself losing hour after hour to things such as: Not using the correct commands when I'm trying to download something from GitHub, not using the correct file structure, not giving path to my compiler correctly, not configuring dependent libraries properly, not building a library properly, not building my own code properly and so on.

It is almost certainly a situation of I don't know what I don't know, but I have the feeling a lot of the pain comes from skills not directly related to coding, but a light form of software development. I would like to learn about CMake, using compliers properly, how to download and link a library properly, and similar things. When a given software is well-documented and provides me with an example CMakeLists.txt file then I can sort it out. If it does not, then I might as well not even bother downloading the library because I won't figure it out.

Thus I'm asking for a book that would teach me those things from a standpoint of what I need to know and not too, too much else (we all want to get the code working and do the more fun stuff, right?) Bonus points if it covers git. I feel it would be a good experience for me to try to contribute to some of these libraries as I become capable. It doesn't have to be a book necessarily, but a mostly self-contained resource would be great. Trying to fit several pieces of the solution together from multiple sources, is what I have been doing and has lead me here.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit/Addendum: Maybe another piece of the puzzle here is that I lack knowledge of bash commands and probably also have a lot to learn about Ubuntu. Again, I'm hoping I've given enough information to give an idea of the type of things I feel hold me back. So that even though I don't know what I don't know, you all will be able to provide some helpful suggestions.

Comment: Attend a Software Carpentry course in your area, perhaps? Or just use their materials online?

Comment: Thank you very much. That looks like a valuable source of information on git and bash.

Comment: You probably don't want a book (not sure one exists), I don't think that C++ is really a key part of your question, though it helps frame where you're coming from. There are many resources out there, you probably just need the right keywords to get you going. Maybe check this out: https://bssw.io/items?category=better-skills